# How to get key of a dictionary in a list or tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

A dict like ,

```
c = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
```

I need to get the keys in list .
I write,

```
x = [c.key()]
```

but that don't work.
how i can do this ?
Can i iterate over key of a dictionary ?
If i write , `c.key()` that needs to return's the keys of `dict c` . But that doesn't do that . Why ?

Comment: did you try `x=c.keys()` ?

Answer (score 3):

In python 3, `c.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object, so to be sure you have a list, you should do:

```
x = list(c.keys())
```

*Casting* is necessary in python 3 because `dict_keys` objects are not *subscriptable*

In python 2, `x = c.keys()` will return a `list`.

**Update:** By default, dictionaries return their keys when you call an [`iterator`](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) on them or try to loop through them directly, so

```
x = list(c) # list of keys

t = tuple(c) # tuple of keys
```

will return a list and tuple of the keys in both python 2 and 3

Comment: gah, just when I thought i knew python, they go ahead and make a new object type -_-

Comment: If you're going to `list`-ify anyway, drop the `.keys()`; `list(c)` will get you a `list` of the `keys` consistently with no additional work on both Py2 and Py3, since `dict`s are iterables of their keys.

Comment: @J.J: It's a big improvement; the keys and items views are set-like, and in all cases they're iterable views on the backing dictionary, so you avoid creating unnecessary shallow copies of the `dict`'s contents. Only case where it hurts is if you're iterating and mutating the `dict` as you go; if you add or remove keys and need to keep iterating, you'd need to wrap the view object in `list` before iterating to explicitly shallow copy.